# xpath find a CSS attribute from DOM not inline

Tags: xpath, styles, background-image, selector, inline-styles

[See my code here of my scenario](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aQ5h.png)I have this scenario and I need to use xpath to validate the image, and the gradient colors are present. I tried all kind of xpath combination but still getting errors or not finding it. Many other samples have the style in-line. In this case  has a "." class outside of a close tag. code in the image

Could some offer a hand?`your text`

Comment: Please, can you provide the code you tried (The code should be pasted as code, not as image) and also if possible the url of the page.

Comment: It was hard to paste code here, the editor was removing tags. Anyway I hope you can see it now. Link won't work it's internal
<div class="X">
            <style>
   .topper__bg:before {
    background: #0f3d70;
   }
   .topper__bg:after {
    background: url() repeat center center;
    background-size: contain;
   }
  </style>